# Show that $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$ implies $f(p) = 0$ for at most one $p \in [a,b]$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Suppose $f \in C[a,b]$ and $f'(x)$ exists on $(a,b)$. Show that if $f'(x)$ not equal to $0$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$, then there can exist at most one number $p$ in $[a,b]$ with $f(p) = 0$.

Is there any theoretical proof available to this Theorem?

Comment: Suppose that two points $p$ and $q$ are such that $f(p)=f(q)=0$. Can you use Rolle's theorem on $(p,q)$ to conclude?

Comment: Hi, below answer from Mr. P Vanchinathan is correct. Rolle's Theorem doesn't apply.

Comment: Of course it applies. Said another way, since $f'(x)$ exists on $(a,b)$ and $f \in C[a,b]$, a derivative constantly steering clear of zero would imply a strictly increasing or decreasing function in the interval. I am trying to argue by contradiction, which is why I had to use Rolle's theorem.

Comment: There is a point to prove f(p)=0 also.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the derivative function $f'(x)$ is continuous on an interval. Then  on that interval it is always positive or always negative, being never zero. Consequently $f(x)$ will be either increasing or decreasing throughout that interval. And so $f(x)$ cannot take the same value twice (zero or whatever).

Comment: I don't think you need to assume that $f^{\prime}$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes. this is the correct solution and thanks for it.

Comment: @RamSKumar: There is a procedure for accepting an answer which you should do when satisfied.